# Replacing rsyslog with journald for a more modern approach of logging

Tags: logs, rsyslog, systemd-journald

I'm looking for a more modern way of keeping logs my Linux servers. Rsyslog still strongly relies on logrotate to keep logs maintainable and space occupation by logs to a minimum, which is not a recommended approach anymore these times. Instead, the log-writer should be the same as the log-rotator to avoid any data loss and other issues, as described thoroughly here: [FGA: Don't use logrotate or newsyslog in this century](http://jdebp.uk/FGA/do-not-use-logrotate.html)

**My goal is to:**

- keep log maintenance simple and provide a lot tools to check and manipulate the output of logs
- avoid issues with space exceeding and avoid config overhead to prevent this. Also avoid log duplication
- avoid issues with logs that are forever kept open and the `copytruncate` option should be used, resulting in data loss of logging that happens during the truncate process. Or with the alternative approach where services need to be force restarted
- still keep it simple to implement forward to a central logging server/database (like Elasticsearch)

According to my experience, this isn't possible with rsyslog + logrotate without too much effort, but journald seems to meet at least all those criteria, so I want to use it exclusively and remove rsyslog for the already described purpose and as well as to remove existing log duplication (when journald `storage=persistent`).

**Details about why I think journald fits this goal perfectly:**

- It's intelligent enough to maintain logs and space usage automatically (consistent format, space usage based on available space on the partition)
- A lot of software is already compatible with it (docker has a journald logging backend, there's journalbeat for log processing and sending them to Logstash)
- It doesn't rely on "dump" cron jobs handling the rotation scheduling
- Lots of tools to check the logs
- No issues with log files kept open
- It's already built in all popular server distros and requires minimal configuration
- Handles permissions properly and requires on membership to the `adm` or `systemd-journal` group to access them

**The issues that I see with journald are:**

- The logs are in binary format and they don't allow text-based parsing with external tools (e.g. the Zabbix agent can't parse those logs and alert based on certain triggers). Although this could still be done with the logs in the central log database.

**What I want to know is whether I'm overseeing or missing some crucial information which makes this approach a risky.** I see that commercial distros such as Red Hat Linux and SUSE Enterprise Linux still include rsyslog, although that could just be for compatibility reasons and don't require it to be used. Note that this solution should be considered as a generic solution compatible with any distro.

Comment: Read this article and let me know does it suit your needs: https://fitzcarraldoblog.wordpress.com/2014/09/20/change-systemds-binary-logging-to-text-logging-in-sabayon-linux/

Comment: @Sysadmin It's actually the opposite of what I want to achieve. I want to avoid duplicating those logs. But I appreciate your suggestion

Comment: Hmm. I have no idea is Kiwi Syslog something what you could use, because I do not know how it works exactly. I just thought that you can check it. If you know that there are tools like Elasticsearch, Grafana, Graylog, Zabbix I just thought that it may be something what is worth to mention. By the way I can check in free time is there any tool which will suit your needs, but I am not sure. Anyway thanks for this thread. Worth to reconsider.